# dealing with meta tags when i cannot know in advance how many there are

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am trying to analyse meta tags (specifically article:tag) in external documents, the url of which are passed to me by the user.

I have looked at several likely sources and there is no consistency in how they use the tag:

1. Some don't use the tag
2. Some have use multiple tags
3. Some use a single tag with comma-delimited keywords/phrases
4. Some use one tag with a description-type entry

What I need to do is get the value (whether across multiple tags, comma delimited or description-type) into a single string

i'm using the htmlAgility Pack and am able to get other values (when I know there is only one or none) with the following code:

```
//get html
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(sourceHtml);
var artAuthor = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@property='article:author']");
try
{
    strARTAuthor = artAuthor.Attributes["content"].Value;
}
catch
{
    strARTAuthor = "";
}
```

and I suspect I need a foreach somewhere but I'm not sure exactly how this should be constructed.

Putting something along the lines of

```
foreach(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@property='article:tag']") in htmldoc)
```

doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly all types of `meta` tag you have observed, but at least, you need to use `SelectNodes()` replacing `SelectSingleNode()` to make the `foreach` loop to work :

```
var metas = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta[@property='article:tag']");
foreach(HtmlNode meta in metas)
{
    .....
}
```